# Sitecore development. Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl.GetCacheKey() throws NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, sitecore

I just click submit button and got an exception. Unable to debug, because this happens before the submit event handler work.
I tried to clear sitecore caches, browser caches and cookies... nothing helps.

here the stack trace.

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl.GetCacheKey() +242
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +61
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +17
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1266

Comment: What version? What do you mean by "submit button"? What page exactly are we talking about? Is this some Sitecore tool or a content page you've created? Have you tried an iisreset?!

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore Version 6
The page - a content page with sublayout, represented by my own UserControl which contains a submit button.
Yes, I've tried iisreset, does not help.

Comment: Similar situation here. Content page with sublayout. My sublayout consists of simple asp components (place holders, buttons and a <asp:Login>, with some simple event handling C# code behind wither embedded in the .ascx, or in the codebehind file. IIS Reset doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I answered my own question eventually!**

I found a solution that worked for me on [this blog](http://www.neilpullinger.co.uk/2008/04/postback-opens-layout-rather-than.html).

It seems you need to make sure that your **App_Browser** folder in intact and well. Mine had gone missing when I cloned the site files. Doh!

Speciffically, make sure you have an `App_Browsers\Form.browser` file in the root of your site, which contains, at a minimum,

`<adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm"
adapterType="Sitecore.Web.FormAdapter, Sitecore.Kernel" />`

Hope this helps!

**My original "Answer Question"**

> Anyone else having this problem? Or
>   did this ever get resolved?
>
> I have the same problem.
>
> I have a few pages with my own custom
>   sublayouts. One one page is an
>   `<asp:Login>` and another just has an
>   `<asp:Button>`. As soon as the "Login"
>   button is clicked, or the button on
>   the other page is clicked, and before
>   any code-behind is executed, I get a
>   null reference exception exactly as in
>   the question above.
>
> The exact same sub layout works on a
>   different clone of the website (we
>   have just finished copying and
>   re-purposing the site) - so this
>   should be some kind of config problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just chased down a problem on my development environment and eventually found that App_Browsers\Form.browser (and XamlPage.browser for that matter) all of a sudden had gone missing....!?

Anyone have a clue as to what can make these go away? :-)